# Unable to boot from recovery partition after unistalling Ubuntu 12.04 64bit

Tags: 12.04, boot, windows-7

I have Sony VAIO laptop of E-series. One day I installed Ubuntu 12.04 64bit on my machine, but it is not useful for me. So I uninstalled Ubuntu and now I'm unable to boot from my recovery partition & Win7 64bit.

How can I regain my system to factory settings?

Comment: How did you uninstall ubuntu 12.04? are you referring to Wubi?

Answer (score 1):

There are some [third-party utilities](http://download.cnet.com/1770-20_4-0.html?query=boot%20loader&rpp=10&searchtype=downloads&filter=platform=Windows&filterName=platform=Windows) that will repair the Windows boot-loader. One that I found useful and easy was [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/), but that was years ago.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem yesterday (I had formatted the Ubuntu partition which turned out to have had contained the Grub settings) and made it work again this way:

1. Run the Windows install DVD
2. Go to system restore options (I don't exactly remember what it is called) and choose command prompt from the list.
3. Execute the following command (replace [DRIVE] with drive letter):

   ```
   bootsect /nt60 [DRIVE]: /mbr
   ```

   Maybe it also works if you use "SYS" instead of a drive letter, I don't know.

This solved it for me, good luck.

Edit: Did some research on Google. It seems you can use "SYS" as well instead of a drive letter, the command can then look like the following:

```
bootsect /nt60 SYS /mbr"
```